# Stay in Institution or Move to a new institution

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, university, qualifying-exam

Last time I reported that I had failed my qualifier and now have been asked to leave.  In that time, I have done the prep work to exit out of with my masters with a presentation for my Masters work and the writing all but finished.  My advisor seems to have abandoned me because, mostly, of how the qualifier went and well as not being impressed by my presentation (he's more of a hands-off approach).

A few months later I have been accepted into a Ph.D. program (of a different major).  However, something is still possessing me to fight to stay in my original program and continue either with my advisor or move on to a new one.

Is it worth my time trying to contest my qualifier and stay in the program or should I just move on?  Keep in mind that I do like the work that I have done with my advisor but am still flexible to move on to another professor.

Comment: Do you have someone willing to fight for you and advise you in your current university that you want to be advised by? If the answer is no, I can't imagine a reason to stay for very long.

Comment: So you have been told to leave (a decision not usually taken lightly, but is department dependent), have an exit strategy in hand, and are asking if it is worth your time to tilt at windmills to stay somewhere that you are not welcome anymore? What good, exactly, will contesting anything do you?

Comment: @PVAL I might, but I am seeing if this advisor is serious about the commitment.

Comment: @JonCuster I keep at the department, fight for my research and ultimately come out with a Ph.D is the best case.  Worst case, I actually tried, gave it my all and leave without any regrets and start over new.

Comment: @user1449249 - Fair enough answer. My reply would be that you are trapped in a fallacy of sunk cost. From your description, there is no logical reason to believe you will win and triumph. Get out now and use your energies to move forward.

Comment: @JonCuster Althought I can't upvote you, you make a great response and I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have failed your qualifying exam, it is entirely possible that you may not have the option of "fighting" at your current institution. Your degree candidacy may have been ended, and leaving with a master's is the best available outcome.

You should check with the chair of graduate studies for your department to see what options you have available.

However, in general, your path of least resistance would be to start over elsewhere. Overcoming a failed qualifier is difficult at best, even when it is possible.

Comment: This as well as JonCuster's response are probably the best response that I've had.  Thank you.